# IE11 incompatibility with jQuery's 'readonly'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

The code I'm running has no issues in Firefox, or Chrome. A user is typing into one textbox, tabs to the next and can continue typing into that.

When I run the webpage on IE11, a user tabs to the next textbox and can't type anything in. The textbox has to be double-clicked before the user can insert anything.

I've googled this and it seems that sometimes IE will give problems when using some older jQuery (i.e. it prefers `'prop'` to `'attr'`). In the code below is jQuery's `readonly` keyword being used in a way that IE11 will no longer recognise/accept?

I assume the issue is with `readonly`, as the `removeClass('ignore')` is working as expected.

```
 //when focus is on textbox 1
  $("#Field1").focus(function() {

        //remove readonly property from textbox 1
         $('#Field1').prop('readonly', false).removeClass('ignore');

          //add readonly property to all other textboxes
         $('#Field2, #Field3, #Field4')
                .prop('readonly', 'readonly').addClass('ignore').val(''); 
});
```

I'm using jQuery 2.1.3

Comment: .prop deals with internal DOM-specific stuff, e.g. tagName, nodeName, etc... you want `attr`, which deals with html-level ATTRIBUTEs, like `readonly`.

Comment: When asking about property and attribute jQuery methods, it is important to know what version of jQuery is being used.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: That is a weird design pattern of adding and removing readOnly attribute. I am betting same issue would happen if it was just pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$('#Field1').attr('readonly', false).removeClass('ignore');
```

To:

```
$('#Field1').removeAttr('readonly').removeClass('ignore');
```

readonly is a ***boolean attribute*** and as per the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-readonly-attribute):

> The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So in this case setting to false has no effect and you want to remove the attribute entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it and no change, unfortunately.

Comment: As far as I know `prop()` is a concept specific to jQuery (it's not `attr()`). I'm not sure what that has to do with your HTML standard justification.

Comment: @Bruno your right, I missed the difference at first look. It should use attr and I've edited to reflect that, I still believe that following the standard is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean for the property value, not a string

```
$('#Field2, #Field3, #Field4')
            .prop('readonly', true).addClass('ignore').val('');
```

Comment: In this case the only valid value for readonly is the string "readonly" to specify false the attribute should be removed

Comment: @dmck been doing this for years with `disabled, readonly, checked` and others with no problems whatsoever. Can also use `removeProp()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it and no change, unfortunately.

Comment: is focus triggered on the `readonly` ? Doesn't really make sense to have it readonly in the first place if you remove it on focus. Seems that you are only looking for style effect and shouldn't use readonly at all

Answer (score 0):

I have used Focusin() function in jquery side with Id.
When I click on textbox then we remove readony attribute as below:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCustomerSearch" readonly class="customer-search" placeholder="Search customer:" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off">
```

**Jquery**:

```
$("#txtCustomerSearch").focusin(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

it will working in IE11 and other browser.